# Humans have energy, but not water. What happens?

Tags: technology, humans, energy-beings

Suppose that through a "hand-wavium" genetic engineering coupled with nanotechnology the humanity was able to develop a **body battery**.

How does this work? It provides enough **energy** for the human body. No need to use glycogen/glucose ATP mechanism.

Let's suppose that heat regulation is also solved by this technology.

I suppose humans would still need to feed themselves (because of proteins/vitamins/minerals) and drink water.

So what would happen if this battery-human is lost in a desert without access to water? Would he/she die as fast as a regular human? What would be the difference? How can this be circumvented?

Comment: Hello Chaotic.  Please remember that SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  I count 3 questions.  Could you narrow your question to just one?

Comment: @JBH To my eyes, they are the same question asked 3 different ways...

Comment: @ArkensteinXII,(a) would a person die as quickly as an unmodified person? is a yes/no question.  (b) what's the difference? is similar and might be considered the same.  (c) How can this be circumvented? is an entirely different question.  Good question behavior is to ask just one question to remove ambiguity and reduce the likelihood of being closed as too-broad.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "suppose that heat regulation is also solved"? Do you mean that the human is completely immune to hot and cold environments, or just that we shouldn't worry about the heat generated by the battery itself?

Comment: What happens is WWIII. How that can be circumvented is still up in the air. - *What would happen to **a** human who doesn't need to eat food, lost in a desert without access to water?* The average is three days without water, and a few weeks w/o food.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They would die of thirst just like any other human.

Consider: an unmodified human can live about a month without food. You won't be living very *well* after a month with no food, but it can be done.

On the other hand, you will die after mere days without water.

Simply put, access to energy is not a limiting factor over the same timescales that access to water is. Human bodies already have *tons* of stored energy that could have kept us going long after we otherwise die of dehydration. So, for these purposes, the body battery is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know about tonnes, but I have around 20Kg more stored energy than I should have...

Comment: The survival rule of 3 - 3 minutes without air, 3 days without water, 3 weeks without food. Might save your life someday!

Answer (score 8):

Water is used for other things besides the Krebbs cycle and respiration. It is structural. The citoplasma in human cells and blood plasma are mostly water. Water is also used in osmoregulation and thermoregulation.

Your superhero may endup dead faster than a regular person in a desert. When I think of batteries, I usually think of three things:

- Chemical wastes, which need to be eliminated from the body through urine, sweat or feces (which will require some water);
- Heat - the battery will be generating it, and guess what the body will use as a heat sink?
- One of Metallica's best songs, but that's neither here nor there.

Bottom line being, this thing will not save you water. You've probably installed it to be able to draw more muscle power or whatever, so you are probably drying up faster as a consequence.

Answer (score 3):

## They would be fine.

In the desert, it is hot, and there is no water. However since you're using hand-wavium, and apparently the "heat regulation" problem is solved, then there shouldn't be a problem with surviving in the desert.

## Unless:

1. The heat regulation properties of the technology need water to operate. Like if they still sweat.
2. The technology stops operating properly at high temperatures.
3. They need water to survive for some other reason, like expelling liquid waste.